# ConstraintValidator is not working (how can I do it?)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I will try to explain it as simple as I can.  I have one entity class, one service, one repository.

User.class

```java
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@UniqueEmail
private String email;
```

UserRepo

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

   boolean findByEmail(String email);

}
```

UserService

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }


    public UserResponseDTO createUser(UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO){
        userRequestDTO.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userRequestDTO.getPassword()));
        User u = userRepository.save(UserMapper.INSTANCE.entityToDto(userRequestDTO));
        return UserMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(u);
    }

    public boolean findUserByUserName(String email){

        if(userRepository.findByUsername(email)){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public boolean findUserByUserEmail(String email){

        if(userRepository.findByEmail(email)){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

UserController

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UserController {


   private final String endPointName = "api";


   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;


   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
   @PostMapping(path = endPointName+"/addUser", consumes = "application/json")
   public GenericResponseMessage addUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO){

      userService.createUser(userRequestDTO);
      return new GenericResponseMessage("ok");

   }

}
```

Validator Annotation

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface UniqueEmail {

   public String message() default "There is already user with this email!";

   public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};

}
```

UniqueEmailValidator class

```java
@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      return value != null && !userService.findUserByUserEmail(value);
   }

}
```

**[API ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue8N1.png)**

```json
{
     "timestamp": "2022-11-23T08:51:07.717+00:00",
     "status": 500,
     "error": "Internal Server Error",
     "trace": "javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.\n\tat org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:186)\n\tat org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:62)\n\tat org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75)\n\tat org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130)\n\tat org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123)\n\tat org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)\n\tat bla bla bla",
     "message": "HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.",
     "path": "/api/addUser"
}
```

INTELLIJ ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at mywebapp.demowebapp.constraint.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:22) ~[main/:na]
at mywebapp.demowebapp.constraint.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:13) ~[main/:na]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:180) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:62) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at mywebapp.demowebapp.service.UserService.createUser(UserService.java:35) ~[main/:na]
at mywebapp.demowebapp.controller.UserController.addUser(UserController.java:32) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I added `@Component` annotation **but it did not work.**

I edit and try `@Valid` annotation `@Valited` ***but it did not work***.

I add

"spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none"

in application.properties file. If I add this, **the error goes away but the "validation" in the whole system is disabled.**

If I remove

**"spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none"**

all validations like @NotNull, @NotEmpty, @Pattern etc are working except the annotation I created.

But if I add

**"spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none"**

all of them are disabled, and the data is entered into the database without any checks.

Comment: I cannot see the  createUser method in UserService. Do you have it?

Comment: @Tris hello yes ı have. I wanted to write as short as possible, so I removed the unnecessary parts. I have now edited it again.

Comment: I see that you are applying validation to User which is an entity object, did you try with the validation in DTO object UserRequestDTO which you actually get in REST layer. There is no point going to DAO layer if the request is not valid. The code which might be causing issue 'User u = userRepository.save(UserMapper.INSTANCE.entityToDto(userRequestDTO));'

Comment: @Tris As you mentioned, the User object is in my Entity layer. However, I was getting UserDTO in the controller. 

For this reason, since there was no control in UserDTO, "Null" was coming to the validation section when transferring data between layers.

For this reason, the program was giving Null error while running. 

I removed all annotations from the user entity class and transferred all validation annotations to "userdto". 

The problem was solved in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the autowiring of your `UserService` does not work correctly which leads to a NPE when the validator tries to call the `findUserByUserEmail` on your `UserService`. Try the following validator:

```java
@Documented
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmail.Validator.class)
public @interface UniqueEmail {

    String message() default "There is already a user with this email!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class Validator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Override
        public void initialize(UniqueEmail constraintAnnotation) {}

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            return value != null && !userService.findUserByUserEmail(value);
        }

    }
}
```

Make sure to define a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` as well:

```java
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

For me, this apporach worked at several places.

By the way, I strongly recommend using exists queries instead of find queries and then checking if the object is not null. With your way, you load the whole entity from the database just to check if it is present. It is much more performant if you let your JPA provider execute a SQL exists query instead. You can write exists queries in your repository as follows:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

   boolean existsByEmail(String email);

   boolean existsByUsername(String email);

}
```

For more information check the [Spring Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject) or this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-exists-query).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time but we have already done the same things. 

The only difference between the codes is that I created it in an external class and you created it nested. 

If you look at my codes I shared above, the userservice is already marked as @autowired. 

Validator does not see the repository or service layer I added in it. The problem is exactly here.  

Thank you for your time, but I already wrote the same code, please review my code again, you will see that we are doing the same thing. 

The result is the same, nothing has changed.

Comment: Hi @smhsmh, I added a configuration bean that I have also used in my projects. Could you try again with said config bean?

Comment: Hi @Times Is there a special way to add it or should I create a configuration package and then add it directly?

Comment: I have a package named `config` where I place all my `@Configuration` beans but it is up to you. If you have all your validation logic in a `validation` package you could also place it there. All that matters is that the class is annotated with `@Configuration` and that the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is declared as a `@Bean` there :)

Comment: LocalValidatorFactoryBean  is configured automatically in Spring Boot.

Comment: @Hantsy yet it was needed to make it work. You sure about this? ;)

Comment: @Times I am 100% sure it is not required. Check my example link and research yourself.

Comment: @times29 Hello I know its been a long time since you last checked this post but I have ran into this same problem and no matter what I try my userService is still null


edit:  I made it work but like smhylc answer I had to move them to the api RequestDTO is there any specific reason why does it work there?

Answer (score 1):

I created an example project based on your code fragments in your original post.

But I slightly changed the implementation of ConstraintValidator.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {
    private final UserAccountRepository userAccounts;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueEmail constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(value)) {
            return !userAccounts.existsByEmail(value);
        }

        // empty or blank text, skip to use @NotBlank @NotEmpty to validate it.
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I added a simple test to verify it.

```java
@Test
public void testSaveUserAccount() throws Exception {
        when(userAccounts.existsByEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        var body = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(new CreateUserAccountCommand("foo@bar.com", "test"));
        mockMvc.perform(post("/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(body))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

        verify(userAccounts, atLeastOnce()).existsByEmail(anyString());
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(userAccounts);
}
```

Run the tests in IDE, you can the constraints violations in the console like this.

```bash
[Field error in object 'createUserAccountCommand' on field 'email': 
rejected value [foo@bar.com]; 
codes [UniqueEmail.createUserAccountCommand.email,UniqueEmail.email,UniqueEmail.java.lang.String,UniqueEmail];
 arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [createUserAccountCommand.email,email]; 
arguments []; default message [email]]; 
default message [There is already user with this email!]] ]
```

Check [my example project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/custom-validator) from my Github.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my side

ı have user entity class I removed all validation annotations from the pure entity class.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userid;
    private String username;
    private String userDisplayName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

}
```

UserDTO -> I put all the properties related to validation in the DTO class and requested the DTO data from the client in the controller layer.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserRequestDTO implements Serializable {


    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2,max = 20)
    private String username;


    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2,max = 20)
    @UsernameControl
    private String email;



    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String userDisplayName;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

}
```

**thanks to these 2 wonderful people for their ideas and for helping me solve the problem**:[Hantsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893898/hantsy) and [Times](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5151202/times)

Comment: This is generally a good approach as you can stop processing a request earlier in comparison to when the entity is persisted. You might have already executed several requests before the validation was triggered. Glad I could help :)